# SSO From Flask to Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, flask

I have a dashboard in flask and it has links to other apps. One of the links is to a Spring Boot app in which I already have form login authentication configured.

What is a good approach to allow a user to login to the Spring App from my dashboard in Flask?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.